# prepareForSegue passes data when Modal but does not Show Navegation Title and back button, and Push crashes and does not Work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a code that passes data from one Table View to a ViewController. This is how they look

[image: As you can see the Style is Modal]

Using Modal Segue it passes the Data correctly to the View controller but it does not show the Navegation Controller, it does when i change it to push but it wont pass the Values to the other View. Here is my

UserTableViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showUserDetail"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        UserDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSDictionary *dict = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        destViewController.labelName = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];
        destViewController.labelRate = [dict valueForKey:@"rate"];
        destViewController.labelBio = [dict valueForKey:@"bio"];

    }
}
```

And when i Change it to PUSH i Get the following Error on the Console Log

2014-05-19 09:52:26.660 mobile-app[7075:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'showUserDetail'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x017f81e4 **exceptionPreprocess + 180
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015778e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
        2   UIKit                               0x007acc8f -[UIStoryboardPushSegue destinationContainmentContext] + 0
        3   UIKit                               0x0079bf0c -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 174
        4   UIKit                               0x0079bf87 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
        5   UIKit                               0x00321965 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1453
        6   UIKit                               0x00321b14 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 279
        7   UIKit                               0x0032610e __38-[UITableView touchesEnded:withEvent:]_block_invoke + 43
        8   UIKit                               0x002550aa ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15
        9   UIKit                               0x00255055 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 403
        10  UIKit                               0x00254e76 _afterCACommitHandler + 532
        11  CoreFoundation                      0x017c036e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 30
        12  CoreFoundation                      0x017c02bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
        13  CoreFoundation                      0x0179e254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
        14  CoreFoundation                      0x0179d9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
        15  CoreFoundation                      0x0179d7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
        16  GraphicsServices                    0x037ec5ee GSEventRunModal + 192
        17  GraphicsServices                    0x037ec42b GSEventRun + 104
        18  UIKit                               0x00237f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
        19  mobile-app                          0x0000559d main + 141
        20  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e3f701 start + 1
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)

Comment: i see the search controller is define as initial controller in storyboard, see the arrow. that why you are getting generic error , for not embaded in navigation controller. change it to  first view controller in storyboard.

Comment: I changed the Initial view controller to the Login Window and now it shows using Push :) Thank you and thansk for taking the time to answer. Have a nice Day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see the search controller is define as initial controller in storyboard, see the arrow. that why you are getting generic error , for not embaded in navigation controller. change it to  first view controller in storyboard.

it will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

From the screenshot I can see that `UserTableViewController` is set as the initial view controller, make the navigation controller the initial view controller.

Answer (score 1):

make the navigation controller the initial view controller in user tableViewcontroller and add the UInavigationcontroller to user detail viewcontroller